# MS Excel to Limit Data in Range of Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I know this is not a coding service where I ask for something and you spit out a result.  I am looking for the following help:

say I have 2 unique text data that I can assign to a cell (via data validation or typing in each cell) on a row of 7 cells. Now say I want to allow the text to be assigned to only 3 of those 7 cells each . Is this possible?  If any text is selected more than 3 times within the 7 cells I return an error or grey out the remaining cells?  In other words, once I input the data in a cell, it loops through the 7 cells and counts the number of unique text data found. if more than three of the same text data is found then error, else allow text input..

Any info on this is helpful. Links etc.  I am very grateful for any insight.

PS I know a bit about data validation and vba macros. Just looking for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use`=countif` ? or search for "countif multiple criteria" or try to read the other question here. Try to search this question. "Wrong cell when conditional formatting with values".

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     'Let Range("A1:G1") be the seven cells

     If Union(Range("A1:G1"), Target).Address = Range("A1:G1").Address Then
         If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:G1"), Target.Value) > 3 Then
            MsgBox "Cannot input " & Target.Value & " more than 3 times."
            Target = ""  'Erase
         End If
     End If
End Sub
```